# Login authentication via LDAP

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

How can one process an employee login using the company LDAP's directory with a username and password?

Comment: you can vote up for me as well :) since it helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check these two links, LDAP is using the active directly to authenticate users.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649227.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18742/Simple-Active-Directory-Authentication-Using-LDAP

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the ASP.NET Membership Provider? There's an [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx) that can handle authentication to Active Directory. I'm not sure if it'll work with a pure LDAP server, or if you are using AD, but this might get you started in the right direction.

Comment: You can find a generic LDAP Membership Provider here: http://code.google.com/p/njupiter/wiki/nJupiterDataAccessLdap that will work with more than just an Active Directory